# Nullable associations if fields are blank

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24442182/how-to-ignore-validation-annotation-if-field-is-blank).

I have these classes

```
 Class Parent

{
   [Required]
   String Name ;

   Child child ;
}

Class Child
{
   StringFirstName ;
   String LastName ;
}
```

I have implemented a custom validation method that passes if both FirstName and LastName are empty or filled but fails if only one of them if filled. What I need is to tell EF that if both Firstname and LastName are empty set the child association in Parent to null. Now it creates a record for child with empty strings if both are empty.

Comment: A child's first/last name is another child!?

Comment: Change the first and last name to string... If you have child... It doesn't make any sense..